# Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 and remove BOM?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

We have a data entry person who encoded in UTF-16 on Windows and would like to have utf-8 and remove the BOM. The utf-8 conversion works but BOM is still there. How would I remove this? This is what I currently have:

```
batch_3={'src':'/Users/jt/src','dest':'/Users/jt/dest/'}
batches=[batch_3]

for b in batches:
  s_files=os.listdir(b['src'])
  for file_name in s_files:
    ff_name = os.path.join(b['src'], file_name)  
    if (os.path.isfile(ff_name) and ff_name.endswith('.json')):
      print ff_name
      target_file_name=os.path.join(b['dest'], file_name)
      BLOCKSIZE = 1048576
      with codecs.open(ff_name, "r", "utf-16-le") as source_file:
        with codecs.open(target_file_name, "w+", "utf-8") as target_file:
          while True:
            contents = source_file.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
              break
            target_file.write(contents)
```

If I hexdump -C I see:

```
Wed Jan 11$ hexdump -C svy-m-317.json 
00000000  ef bb bf 7b 0d 0a 20 20  20 20 22 6e 61 6d 65 22  |...{..    "name"|
00000010  3a 22 53 61 76 6f 72 79  20 4d 61 6c 69 62 75 2d  |:"Savory Malibu-|
```

in the resulting file. How do I remove the BOM?

thx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use [`str.decode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) and [`str.encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
with open(ff_name, 'rb') as source_file:
  with open(target_file_name, 'w+b') as dest_file:
    contents = source_file.read()
    dest_file.write(contents.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))
```

`str.decode` will get rid of the BOM for you (and deduce the endianness).

Comment: cool - works well, do  you know how to add a crlf -> lf conversion facility in the read? thx if you can help

Comment: That approach (storing the entire file in memory twice) isn't very efficient, if you're working with large files.

Answer (score 41):

This is the difference between `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16`

- `UTF-16LE` is little endian **without** a BOM
- `UTF-16` is big or little endian **with** a BOM

So when you use `UTF-16LE`, the BOM is just part of the text.  Use `UTF-16` instead, so the BOM is automatically removed.  The reason `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16BE` exist is so people can carry around "properly-encoded" text without BOMs, which does not apply to you.

Note what happens when you encode using one encoding and decode using the other.  (`UTF-16` automatically detects `UTF-16LE` sometimes, not always.)

```
>>> u'Hello, world'.encode('UTF-16LE')
'H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00,\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00'
>>> u'Hello, world'.encode('UTF-16')
'\xff\xfeH\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00,\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00'
 ^^^^^^^^ (BOM)

>>> u'Hello, world'.encode('UTF-16LE').decode('UTF-16')
u'Hello, world'
>>> u'Hello, world'.encode('UTF-16').decode('UTF-16LE')
u'\ufeffHello, world'
    ^^^^ (BOM)
```

Or you can do this at the shell:

```
for x in * ; do iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 <"$x" | dos2unix >"$x.tmp" && mv "$x.tmp" "$x"; done
```