# UTF-16 big endian encoding with a byte-order mark

Tags: python, encoding

I created a file with just an em dash in it in Notepad and saved this file with `Unicode (big endian)` encoding. In Notepad, this displays an em dash. When I open the file and read it like this in Python 3/IDLE:

```
open(file_path, encoding="UTF-16-BE").read()
```

I get this:

```
'\ufeff—'
```

Expressed as bytes, the files contents are this:

```
b'\xfe\xff \x14'
```

Shouldn't it be handling the BOM and not displaying it? I looked at the available encodings for Python and there was nothing like a `UTF_16_BE_SIG` in there as there is for `UTF_8_SIG`. What is going on here and how do I handle it properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827419/converting-utf-16-utf-8-and-remove-bom

Comment: @Robᵩ - I like your answer better than the linked answer so I'd vote not to dup.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the endianness of UTF-16, you disable the BOM check. If you want the codec to examine and remove the BOM, specify the non-endian codec:

```
open(file_path, encoding="UTF-16").read()
```